# Find all possible copmbinations from prolog database lists

Tags: prolog

I have the following database for my program:

```
letter([a,b,c,d,e,f]).
number([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
```

I want to make a predicate combinations/1 such that it gives the following in- and output:

```
?- combinations(List).
List = [set(a, 6), set(b, 5), set(c, 4), set(d, 3), set(e, 2), set(f, 1)];
List = ...
```

Then when you use the semicolon (;), it gives a new combination.

This is my best try, but it gives me one big list rather than small ones that I can use backtracking on:

```
combinations(List) :-
    findall((X,Y), (member(X, letter(L1), member(Y, number(L2)), List))).
```

Comment: Your code does not give you one big list. It tries to use `findall/2` which is not defined

Comment: On the one hand, you want lists; on the other hand, you don't want a list of everything. What lists *do* you want? You showed one list you want. Can you show us five others? By what system should the lists be enumerated?

Answer (score 0):

How's this as a starting point:

```
letter_list([a,b,c,d,e,f]).
number_list([1,2,3,4,5,6]).
 
combination(Comb) :-
    number_list(NumLst),
    reverse(NumLst, RevNumLst),
    letter_list(LetLst),
    combination_loop(LetLst, RevNumLst, Comb).
    
combination_loop([HLet|TLet], [HNum|TNum], Comb) :-
    Comb = set(HLet, HNum) ; combination_loop(TLet, TNum, Comb).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- combination(Comb).
Comb = set(a,6) ;
Comb = set(b,5) ;
Comb = set(c,4) ;
Comb = set(d,3) ;
Comb = set(e,2) ;
Comb = set(f,1) ;
false.
```